# Windows installation interrupted

Tags: windows-8, windows-installation

I am trying to install Windows 8 setup using bootable pendrive into my Dell Inspiron Laptop and getting the error: "Windows could not set the offline locale information. Error Code: 0x80FF0000".

Latter I ran pre-boot memory check, which ended with error code : 0146.(Msg Error Code: 2000-0146).

What may be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: How did you tried to install OS ?

Comment: using bootable pendrive. Also tried ubuntu 14.10 but getting error "/install/vmlinuz file not found".

Comment: Check your [Hard Drive is faulty](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how_to_detect_a_faulty_hard_drive_and_recover_data) or not.

Answer (score 1):

This Technet Wiki [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20261.windows-7-windows-could-not-set-the-offline-locale-information-error-during-install.aspx) suggests that the HDD is likely faulty and therefore causing the issue. Could well be worth running some HDD diagnostics.

Comment: Just to be clear, that post says "Windows 7" this happens in Vista, XP and yes, Windows 8. BSOD 0x80FF0000 is caused by a BAD sector on the HDD you're installing on. Try to use another partition (if you have more than one) or replace the HDD if any repair tools you use, do not work.

Comment: Ah... good point, missed that subtle Windows version number. Nice catch @Reeves

Comment: No problem @Dimblefeck - I was about to post an answer when I saw yours popup. Figured I'd just make a note since I was seconds from posting my own after research ;)